# Emacs: Is it possible to expand/collapse single chapters?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In Emacs + org-mode it is possible to collapse the whole text, expand all the subtitles and all the text with SHIFT+TAB.

Is it possible to expand/collapse single chapters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just omit the <kbd>Shift</kbd> and use <kbd>Tab</kbd> only.

Comment: And how can I add tabulation characters?

Comment: @Pietro: As usually, prefix them with `C-q` (`quoted-insert`).

Comment: You mean: C-q TAB ?

Comment: @Pietro: Yes, exactly.